# Enable scrolling on flutter for web

Tags: flutter, scroll, flutter-web

I am currently trying to build a website using flutter for web. Now I want it to be scrollable and not just one simple page.
I tried the following with no success:

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget> [
```

Comment: Hello, What are the issues you are facing? are you able to scroll the page or not?

Comment: what do you mean by be scrollable and not just one simple page

Comment: Use a vertical PageView and you'll get what you need or even a ListView. ScrollViews are terrible because loads everything into memory and performance is affected.

Comment: i just want a scrollable page...

Comment: `SingleChildScrollView` should work if you content is larger than the viewable screen. You need to provide more code for support.